# system call with paths and spaces

Tags: c++, qt, path, escaping, system-calls

I would like to use system()
to
1.open cmd
2.keep it open/ display it
3.run "mybatchfile.bat" from the given path (contains a space)
4.pass "2" as a param.
here is what it looks like `system("cmd.exe /k C:/Users/firstname secondname/desktop/mybatchfile.bat 2");`

when ever I run it I get `"C:/Users/firstname"` is written incorrectly or cannot be found in my command prompt.

How can I fix this? I'm using Qt and Qt uses "/" as a universal directory separator in the same way that "/" is used as a path separator in URLs. so I don't think that's the problem here.

How can I fix this? and is there any other simpler way I can use to pass arguments to batch files in Qt? any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Seen that the space in your path seems to cause it, Can't you try to escape a " ? Like this : `system("cmd.exe /k \"C:/Users/firstname secondname/desktop/mybatchfile.bat\" 2");`  it should solve the problem

Comment: Don't know Qt, but one usually wants to wrap Windows paths in quotes, especially when they have spaces in them

Comment: Qt has nothing to do with it. You will see the same behaviour if you execute `C:/Users/firstname secondname/desktop/mybatchfile.bat 2` at the command line, and the solution to that problem is the same – quote the path.

Comment: @Ariart thank you, that worked, but now it doesn't pass "2" as an argument, does anyone have any idea what I can do about that?

Answer (score 0):

To start programs you can use QProcess like:

```
auto proc = new QProcess();
QString program = QString("\"%1%2\"").arg("C:/Users/firstname secondname/desktop/").arg("mybatchfile.bat");
QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "2";

proc->setWorkingDirectory("C:/Users/firstname secondname/desktop/");
proc->start( program, arguments );
```

This code is not testet but should be runable.

Comment: I tried your code got the following errors:
error: 'mybatchfile' was not declared in this scope
and
error: request for member 'start' in 'proc', which is of pointer type QProcess*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)

Comment: thanks for the edit, i don't get any warning or errors now but it still doesn't seem to do what i would like it to do, my batch is basically:echo 1 - Exit Program      echo 2 - Say Hi       set /p QUESTION=What would you like to do today?:
echo:
IF %QUESTION%==1 GOTO :1
IF %QUESTION%==2 GOTO :2

:1
exit
:2
cls
echo HI   I dont get any output when I execute this code, am i missing something? again thanks a lot for the help!